# regex: how to capture between tags?

Tags: regex

I have these expression

```
<b>hello</b> somthing else <b>world</b>
```

I want to get:

```
[0] = hello
[1] = world
etc...
```

(capturing between tags with no tags)

The goal is not to parse DOM parsing, but only use simple regex

Comment: Please, write what have you done, not only what you want

Comment: Is JS a possible way to go? It would make things much easier, and cleaner. ( using actual DOM, not considering the whole HTML as a single string )

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is a [BAD IDEA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2370483)

Comment: it ois not HTML parsing: it is just a simple tag parsing witjout using DOMs

Answer (score 2):

Everyone writes Regex I will give you other solution you can use PHP function

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($str);
```

To load html from string. Then when you have DOM object you can use method

```
$nodeList = $document->getElementsByTagName('b');

foreach ($nodeList as $b) {
  echo $b->nodeValue ;
}
```

Check these links:

- [DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)
- [The DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: I understand why you've posted this, but what is the StackOverflow "etiquette" on ignoring the tags (even if it is to stop bad-practice and give a much better answer)?

Comment: As I say a lot in the moderation, SO exists to teach people, not just answer questions. It really is a bad idea to use regex to parse HTML (HTML tags can be nested, producing unpredictable results) so it's better to use a parser instead.

Comment: I could write simple regex but it has no sense. It's better to work with DOM. You have access to methods that make calls easier. This example is easy but if he wanted to find some more data with nested attributes he could use other methods from DOMDocument. Also the code is more readable.

Comment: I just need a simple tag string parser, no DOM parsing

Comment: Either you do it good or you does it bad. Your choice my friend.

Comment: @Robert: Don't be dogmatic. As the regex way, using the DOM is not always the most appropriate solution, it depends from where the source comes, how it looks like, what you are trying to do with it... The most important is to continue to think, not to join a so-called consensus.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte if you learn bad habbits from the begining you'll continue to use them in other projects. What if project scale and he needs attributes etc. What if other programmers want to reuse his code? For me regex is less clear than using DOM. I'm not saying it's the most appropriate solution I'm saying that in 90% cases when you have DOM structure you should use DOM objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code;

```
preg_match_all('/<b>.*?<\/b>/is',
"<b>hello</b> somthing<p>wewrw</p> else <b>world</b>",
$out);

print_r($out);
```

Comment: This will also parse ANY other tag. I just need the b tag

Comment: @user300675 `I just need the b tag` you should clarify that in your question

Answer (score 0):

```
$subject = '<b>hello</b> somthing else <b>world</b>';

$pattern = '/<\D>[a-z]{1,}<\/\D>/';

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);print_r($matches);
```